# Need resolution on: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spark versions > 3.2.0 are not yet supported (detected: 3.3.0)

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-20.04, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using spark version 3.3.0 in my job.

I am executing that job from Dataproc cluster of image version -> 2.1.15-ubuntu20

but I am getting below error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spark versions > 3.2.0 are not yet supported (detected: 3.3.0)

Can someone please help in resolving this issue.

[spark_version, cluster_Name(ubuntu_version) and execution_result]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rfO8.png)

Ideally, using spark version **3.3.0** on dataproc cluster image version **2.1.15-ubuntu20**, My job should execute successfully but I am getting below exception.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spark versions > 3.2.0 are not yet supported (detected: 3.3.0)**

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround is based on **Java versioning**. You must make sure that `2.1.15-ubuntu20` has `Java 11 version`. The **2.0.x release** versions has **Java 8 version**, and it not compatible with the 2.1.x release versions.

And if you are using a 3rd party tool, please double check the current version of it. The error you are getting is possibly just because of the versions of the tools and the Java language.